# Is it better to paint wood siding or replace it with vinyl?

Tags: painting, siding, vinyl-siding

I live in Boulder, Colorado. It's time to get my wood siding painted. There will also be a little bit of repair involved. One paint company recommended replacing some sheets of siding, the other 2 recommended Bondo and caulk.

We plan to keep this house a long time. I'm trying to figure out if it would make sense to replace the wood siding with vinyl, or keep painting the wood?

I haven't gotten any vinyl estimates yet. If it's 10X the cost of a paint job then there's no way I'm doing it. If it's more like 2-3X the cost of a paint job then I'm interested in finding out more about tradeoffs.

Comment: -1 This sounds like a shopping question. You'll have to get local quotes from vinyl siding vendors to decide what to do. The multi-geo nature of this site makes cost comparisons here not very useful.

Comment: The trade off is mainly that vinyl is less maintenance, but ugly.

Comment: What kind of wood siding are you talking about?

Comment: It's definitely a shopping question. I didn't realize that wasn't acceptable here. I'm not sure what kind of wood siding it is. I've seen vinyl siding where I have to look very closely to see that it isn't wood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my money and best looks, (if the wood is mostly sound) I would scrape and convert to an solid stain.. Won't peel, can be refreshed over old stain with minor prep (compared to paint)

Fiber cement siding would be my second choice, best durability, low maintenance, bit higher initial cost

Vinyl is not a personal favorite, would depend on what the neighborhood had.

Answer (score 2):

I  would recommend reading up on vinyl siding. It's really not as maintenance free as its manufacturers claim - it fades and becomes brittle. And unlike wood it can't really be repaired.

Not to mention it looks pretty ugly and fake.

Also if your house has any architectural details, then they would probably be covered up by the vinyl installation, significantly reducing curb appeal and possibly valuation of  your home